# Conventional current flow

Tags: current

I have a small doubt. Where does the current prefer to go: in a external resistance region (v>0) or in a short circuit region (v=0)?

Comment: A voltage can't be >0 and =0 at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'external resistance region'? Are you talking about an external load on the circuit?

Comment: Yes sir,  external load

Comment: Current takes **ALL** of the available paths, proportional to the conductivity of each path. Not the shortest path, not the lowest resistance path, but **ALL** paths.

Comment: Please post a schematic describing your question. EESE is kind enough to offer a tool in the editor to allow you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Current flows in all of the paths that exist between one terminal of the power supply and the other. Each path has has a resistance. The amount of current flowing in each of them is determined by the principle of current division.

A short circuit is an unintended current path. The resistance of that path is often assumed to be zero or very much lower than the resistance of any intended current paths. If the resistance of the short circuit is zero, all of the current flows in the short circuit path and no current flows in any other path. If the resistance of the short circuit is very much lower than the resistance of any other path, the other paths are usually ignored and all of the current is assumed to flow in the short circuit.

Comment: Suppose you have 100 amps flowing in that "short circuit", which has 4 squares of copper foil at 0.000500 ohms (500 micro Ohms) per square. The voltage is 100 amps * 0.002 = 0.2 volts. Thus lots of potential to drive current flow. ,,,,,,,,, now suppose the current is 1 milliamp flowing thru the same 4 squares, with the voltage now being 2 microVolts. And this is in the Ground wiring of a 24-bit ADC. What can be ignored? Error budgets help us decide. Where are Error Budgets taught?